# Count primary table rows having at least one reference in other tables

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Assuming there are 3 tables in the database - `classes`, `board` and `tasks`. There is a FK reference of `class_id` from `classes` table in other two tables.

There could be instances where for a particular `class_id`, there are no references in either of the two tables or could have reference in one table but not the other.

Objective is to count all `classes` which have at least one reference in any of the two tables.

What i have tried so far :

```
SELECT COUNT(c.class_id) FROM classes  as c
LEFT JOIN board as b on b.class_id = c.class_id
LEFT JOIN tasks as t on t.class_id = c.class_id
```

This actually returns the count of all instances in the 3 tables whereas the count should of the primary table only.

Comment: Add where clause "where b.class_id IS NOT NULL and t.class_id IS NOT NULL"

Comment: nope. Query still returns a count which is greater than the actual number of classes. How to find the count of classes which have a reference in either of the two tables?

Comment: @Manish shouldn't that be `where b.class_id IS NOT NULL OR t.class_id IS NOT NULL`? (or instead of and)

Comment: @Scorpioo590 this will not work because both board and tasks have no connection between each other.

Comment: ? OP wants to count all classes that have a reference to at least one of the two tables (i.e. in board OR in tasks). Using an AND-conjuntion returns only those classes that are referenced in BOTH (and therefore obviously a result that may be less than the desired result

Comment: @Scorpioo590 yes you are right. Thanks for rectified the code. 1+ from my side also

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments you need an `OR` conjunction to extract those classes that are referenced in `board` OR in `tasks` (this `OR` is not exclusive, meaning a class is also in the result set if it is referenced in both tables).

I prepared a litte fiddle for you to play around: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xaa19Fk25bhtZh9EmGN42w/3

It comes down to this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT classes.class_id)
FROM classes
    LEFT JOIN board ON classes.class_id = board.class_id
    LEFT JOIN tasks ON classes.class_id = tasks.class_id
WHERE board.class_id IS NOT NULL OR tasks.class_id IS NOT NULL;
```

I also included the previous answer to show that it returns the wrong value.
But of course, instead of `DISTINCT` you could also use the `GROUP BY` approach. Just keep the `AND`s and `OR`s in order.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This will resolve your problem

```
Select COUNT(a.class_id) 
FROM ( 
  Select c.class_id FROM classes as c 
  LEFT JOIN board as b on b.class_id = c.class_id 
  LEFT JOIN tasks as t on t.class_id = c.class_id  
  where b.class_id IS NOT NULL OR t.class_id IS NOT NULL 
  Group by c.class_id) as a
```